How to validate that a user has joined a particular telegram group or channel in Node.js
I was working on a Next.js App where I need to verify that whether a user has joined a particular channel or not.
Below is the script which I used in order to do the verification, it first initializes the bot and then checks for ChannelId in order to get call the getchatmember in that server. But during the procedure of getting the channelId it give the below mentioned error. That is cannot get the chatId.
My bot has given all the required permission when it joins a group.
Here is the code
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Telegraf } from "telegraf";

const botToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN;
const channelUsername = "thechannelname";

let bot;
try {
  bot = new Telegraf(botToken);
  console.log("Bot initialized successfully");
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Failed to initialize Telegram bot:", error);
}

//the post request from the client 

export async function POST(req) {
  console.log("Received POST request");

  if (!bot) {
    console.error("Bot not initialized");
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Telegram bot not initialized" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }

  try {
    const payload = await req.json();
    const { session } = payload;
    const telegram = session?.user?.telegram;

    if (!telegram) {
        return NextResponse.json(
        { message: "Telegram username not provided" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    // Get channel info first
    let channelId;
    try {
      console.log("Attempting to get channel info for:", channelUsername);
      const channel = await bot.telegram.getChat(@${channelUsername});
      channelId = channel.id;
    } catch (error) {
       return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: Failed to get channel info: ${
            error.description || error.message
          },
        },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    // Attempt to check membership directly
    try {
      const chatMember = await bot.telegram.getChatMember(channelId, telegram);
      
      const isMember = ["member", "administrator", "creator"].includes(
        chatMember.status
      );

      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          verified: isMember,
          message: isMember
            ? "User is a member of the channel"
            : "User is not a member of the channel",
        },
        { status: 200 }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking channel membership:", error);

      // If direct check fails, we need an alternative verification method
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          verified: false,
          message:
            "Unable to verify membership automatically. Please ask the user to send a message to the bot directly.",
          action: "request_message",
        },
        { status: 202 }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Unexpected error in Telegram verification:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "An unexpected error occurred during verification" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

The Error I'm getting
On the POST request where the client side url is http://localhost:3000/api/verify_telegram with payload contains the session_details.
Error getting channel info: TelegramError: 400: Bad Request: chat not found
    at Telegram.callApi 


Hey, please reduce the example - there's too much irrelevant clutter in there. Additionally, it's not clear from which request to the API endpoint the 400 is coming - could you clarify that as well.

Hello @NotX , I tried to make it as clear as possible, let me know I case of any doubt you have

Well, I still don't really understand which line of the code will lead to this error, so I don't know which request to look at. That said, did you try to run the request with Postman? Once it's working there, you can be sure, that your request, its request headers and its request body are set up correctly.

Hey @shailendra-singh, can you check if your bot is an Admin of the chat you are trying use here. getChatMember only works if the bot is an admin in the channel. You can read more about getChatMember Here

Hello @NavinJethwani, thanks for the suggestion, I have given my bot the admin permission. Here is the problem I faced then.
I can get the channel id https://api.telegram.org/<bot-token>/getChat?chat_id=@channelname
Now getChatMember requires two params chat_id ( which I have ) and user_id which I can not get directly from the username.
So can you please tell me if there is any possible way to get ther user_id from username at the backend  ?

I don't think there is a way to check user_id from username. but when a user sends a message to your bot, the payload will have message.from.id which is user_id which you can use to check if that particular user is a member or not

@NavinJethwani, ya but my application has different requirement, after joining the user don't have to send any message, and searched on the telegram API but there is no direct way to get the user_id, so asked the users to manually enter their user id , which they can easily get with getidsbot .
Thanks for you help!!
